# Как получить мое текущее местоположение?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Ребят использую гугл мап апи надо получить текущее местоположениее(точнее мне надо получить мои координаты ) как это реализовать?буду благодарен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682414/how-to-get-current-location-using-google-maps-api-in-android) ребята уже сталкивались с этим вопросом!